# how to extract particular string with special character from each line of a file

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have a file with a jungle of strings. Few lines read as follows:

```
 2*H[0, 3, y]*Log[1 - z] - 2*H[2, 3, y]*Log[1 - z] +
 6*H[2, 2, 0, y] + 6*H[2, 2, 2, y] - 48*Log[-Q2] + 12*zeta2*Log[-Q2] +
 (-107 + 12*N^2*(-1 + N^2))*z^2))*(H[0, 1, 0, y] + H[0, 1, 0, z] + ...
```

I want to find different unique combination of

```
H[*,*,*] or H[*,*,*,*]
```

coming in each line. Therefore I have to search for string containing special characters too. Is there any way to do in shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this gnu awk command with custom `RS`:

```
awk -v RS='H\\[[^]]*\\]' 'RT && !seen[RT]++{print RT}' file

H[0, 3, y]
H[2, 3, y]
H[2, 2, 0, y]
H[2, 2, 2, y]
H[0, 1, 0, y]
H[0, 1, 0, z]
```

Regex `H\\[[^]]*\\]` will set each instance of `H[...]` as record separator.

Comment: Hi @anubhava .. thanks .It works out of the box. But is there a way to put it in bash as some function for any general string (like "H" here).
Something like
 function test() {awk -v RS="$@\\[[^]]*\\]" 'RT && !seen[RT]++{print RT}' $@ ;}

Comment: Sorry, I did not get it to work. 
Is it possible to put your answer inside bashrc, so that I can use it for any string and file. 
I tried something like 
function myfunc() { awk -v RS='H\\[[^]]*\\]' 'RT && !seen[RT]++{print RT}' $@ ;}
So I run as : myfunc file   and it gives the correct result. But I want to give the prompt input for "H" also, so that it can be used for any general string.

Comment: Inside `.bashrc`  have a function like this: `myfunc() { awk -v RS="$1"'\\[[^]]*\\]' 'RT && !seen[RT]++{print RT}'; }` then call it as `cat file | myfunc 'H'`